# MySql can't add value from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

my DB looks:

[image: DB]

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`contacts` (
  `idcontact` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcontact`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`adresses` (
  `idadress` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `street` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `street_number` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idadress`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`employees` (
  `idemployee` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `adresses_idadress` INT NOT NULL,
  `contacts_idcontact` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idemployee`),
  INDEX `fk_employees_adresses_idx` (`adresses_idadress` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_employees_contacts1_idx` (`contacts_idcontact` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_adresses`
    FOREIGN KEY (`adresses_idadress`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`adresses` (`idadress`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_contacts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contacts_idcontact`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`contacts` (`idcontact`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Then I'am inserting into tables **adresses** and **contacts** like this:

`insert into mydb.contacts(phone,email) values ('123123123','email@gmail.com');
insert into mydb.adresses(city,street,street_number) values ('London','28th Street','13');`

And next I want to insert into **employees**:

`insert into mydb.employees(name,surname) values ('Jack','Reaper');`

And i receive this error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`employees`, CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_adresses` FOREIGN KEY (`adresses_idadress`) REFERENCES `adresses` (idadress) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

What I have to do to repair this?

Comment: You have made a table `employees` with fields `adresses_idadress` and `contacts_idcontact`, and stipulated that they ***can not*** be `NULL`.  So, if you try to add a new record without an address or contact, of course it's going to fail.  Do you want to allow `NULL` values for those two fields or not?  Either remove the `NOT NULL` from the table definition, or specify values for the address and contact when inserting new records.

Comment: I hope you are not under the impression that foreign keys will somehow populate columns in 1 table from another table.

Answer (score 0):

On your insert on employee table, you also have to provide address_isaddress and contact_idcontact. Without that, the insert will not go through.